# Bootstrapped post-hoc analyses for mixed effects models

Tags: r, mixed-model, p-value, bootstrap, post-hoc

I am using Linear Mixed Effects modelling (LMM) to test the effect of a single predictor 'Age' (a 4 level factor: "-1", "1", "3", or "8") on a logit-transformed response variable (percentage herbivory). Because of a nested sampling design I have included 'ID' as a random intercept term.

Following general advice from both online and our university's statistics department, I'm using bootstrapping to obtain parameter confidence intervals and p-values for my predictor variable 'Age'.

I have used the R function `PBmodcomp()` from the `pbkrtest` package (as demonstrated [here](https://datascienceplus.com/introduction-to-bootstrap-with-applications-to-mixed-effect-models/)) to get the bootstrapped p-value from the likelihood ratio test between the model with and without Age:

```
> m <- lmer(herb ~ Age + (1|id), data=d)
> m_0 <- lmer(herb ~ 1 + (1|id), data=d)

> library(pbkrtest)
> PBmodcomp(m, m_0, nsim=1000) 


Parametric bootstrap test; time: 35.90 sec; samples: 1000 extremes: 13;
large : herb ~ Age + (1 | TripletID)
small : herb ~ 1 + (1 | TripletID)
         stat df  p.value   
LRT    14.404  3 0.002404 **
PBtest 14.404    0.013986 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Given that the 'Age' predictor is significant (p=0.013986), I'd like to know how the 4 factor levels differ - i.e. which ages are significantly different from one another.

### My question:

1. Is there a way of performing a 'bootstrapped post-hoc analysis' for mixed effects models in order to get more robust p-values for the pairwise comparisons? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This book may be helpful https://www.crcpress.com/Multiple-Comparisons-Using-R/Bretz-Hothorn-Westfall/p/book/9781584885740.